# hormone treatment (hence the well-built structure of today’s pre-teens) additives?

Tags: meaning

The italicized part evades me. What is the connection between *hormone treatment additives* and *the well-built structure of today's pre-teens*? I mean, 
why is that a cause-effect relationship? Has the well-built structure of today’s pre-teens been brought about by hormone treatment additives? Maybe I lack common sense or something.

> If we are what we eat, what is your teenage child? A bag of chicken
>   and chips? A kebab? Litres of fizzy drink? The benefits of healthy
>   eating and exercise are well documented and it is silly of us, as
>   parents, to think we can feed our teens mostly junk food then expect
>   them to perform at their best. In this age of pesticides, *hormone
>   treatment **(hence the well-built structure of today’s pre-teens)**
>   additives*, etc. that are in foods, both parents and teens need to
>   understand that mental and physical well-being are aligned with what
>   we eat. Depression, aggression, lack of focus, headaches and so much
>   more can be alleviated with the right foods. Be open to this, for
>   yourself and your young person.

source : **Top Tips for Raising Today's Teens**: If You Are Raising Teenagers, Use These Strategies, Exercises and Top Tips 
by Martha Matthews

Comment: The author is making the conclusion that hormone treatment in food affects the development of children, but that's a conclusion that you can feel free to disagree with if you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it ask a medical/health related question, and it is not about learning English. A specific language related question needs to be asked.